# Compiler errors, c++?

Tags: c++

I'm getting these errors. I'm trying to read in from a file and print out the lowest temp year. I have also 2 other files. A file called data.hpp and also data.cpp. In data.hpp is my class definition and in .cpp is the friend overloader.

```
naveed@naveed-VirtualBox:~/Documents/cw$ g++ -Wall analyze.cpp -o analyze
analyze.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
analyze.cpp:11:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘MonthData::MonthData()’
analyze.cpp:11:13: note: candidates are:
data.hpp:14:5: note: MonthData::MonthData(double, int, double, double, int, double,   double)
data.hpp:14:5: note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 0 provided
data.hpp:8:7: note: MonthData::MonthData(const MonthData&)
data.hpp:8:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
analyze.cpp:28:38: error: cannot convert ‘MonthData’ to ‘float’ in initialisation
analyze.cpp:29:30: error: cannot convert ‘MonthData’ to ‘int’ in initialisation
analyze.cpp:30:19: error: ‘o’ was not declared in this scope
analyze.cpp:30:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions     [-Wsign-compare]
analyze.cpp:32:22: error: ‘VectorData’ was not declared in this scope
analyze.cpp:33:9: error: ‘Year’ was not declared in this scope 
analyze.cpp:36:115: error: ‘Year’ was not declared in this scope
analyze.cpp:29:11: warning: unused variable ‘year’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

This is my analyze file:

```
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "data.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 MonthData data;

  vector<MonthData> vectorData;
  ifstream file ("sheffield.data");
  string line;
  int l_num = 0;

  if (file.is_open()) {
    while (getline(file, line))
      if (l_num < 4) {
        l_num += 1;
      }
      else {
        file >> data;
        vectorData.push_back(data);  
      }  

      float MinimumDeg = vectorData[0], getMinTemp();
      int year = vectorData[0], getYear();
      for (int a =o; a < vectorData.size(); a++)
      {
        MinimumDeg = VectorData[a], getMinTemp();
        Year = VectorData[a], getYear();
      }

      cout << "Lowest year and month lowest rainfall: '\n'" << "Min Temp;" << MinimumDeg << "C '\n'" << "Year" << Year << endl;


      return 0;

}  

}
```

I'm trying to read in from a file and print out the lowest temp year.

Comment: The error messages are quite clear and you have not posted your declaration/definition of `MonthData`.

Comment: You need a default constructor for `monthData` and a smattering of other `undeclared variable` errors

Answer (score 0):

Your class MonthData has no default constructor. So this definition of object data

```
MonthData data;
```

is invalid because in this statement the default constructor must be called that is absent.

The default constructor is a constructor that can be invoked without explicitly specified arguments.

Also in these statements

```
  float MinimumDeg = vectorData[0], getMinTemp();
  int year = vectorData[0], getYear();
```

you made a typo and wrote comma instead of period as for example here

```
vectorData[0], getMinTemp()
```

Also in this loop

```
for (int a =o; a < vectorData.size(); a++)
```

you made one more typo and wrote letter 'p' instead of number 0 in initialization of a

Also that to remove the warning change the loop the following way

```
for ( vector<MonthData?::size_type a = 0; a < vectorData.size(); a++)
```

or instead of

```
vector<MonthData?::size_type a = 0;
```

you may write simply

```
size_t a = 0;
```

Also in this loop you use variable `Year` that was not declared. There is declared only variable `year`.

```
  int year = vectorData[0], getYear();
  for (int a =o; a < vectorData.size(); a++)
  {
    MinimumDeg = VectorData[a], getMinTemp();
    Year = VectorData[a], getYear();
  }
```

And again instead of period you use comma in expression

```
    Year = VectorData[a], getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MonthData doesn't declare a 0 parameter constructor.  You need to either write one or use one with the appropriate method signature (like the one requiring 7 parameters).

Like taocp said, you can't assign a MonthData object to a float.

As Vlad mentioned, you have a typo with commas.

Also this line appears to be a typo.  o should be 0 I'm assuming.

```
for (int a =o; a < vectorData.size(); a++)
```

In these lines, you need to lowercase the v in Vector.  VectorData and vectorData are not the same thing in C++.

```
MinimumDeg = VectorData[a], getMinTemp();
Year = VectorData[a], getYear();
```

Same for Year to year in

```
cout << "Lowest year and month lowest rainfall: '\n'" << "Min Temp;" << MinimumDeg << "C '\n'" << "Year" << Year << endl;
```

And given all of this, I'm assuming you never overloaded the >> operator for this line to work:

```
file >> data;
```